# how can I add indents to code in scratch manually or automatically?

Tags: code

How do I manually add indentations in scratch ? auto indentation does not seem to be working for me. I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and right arrow key like on some other text editors.

Is this a bug? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indent manually in Scratch by selecting several lines and pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, or pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Automatic Indentation should occur, where every new line is inserted with the same indentation as the previous line. Automatic Indentation will not actually indent based on brackets or code you write.

Comment: thankyou lewis pressing Tab worked for me really appreciate this, Hope this helps others who were puzzled too.